# Hang on NSManagedObjectContext's save:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

For some reason sometimes my app will just hang with the following code:

```
NSError *error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
     NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

It doesn't always hang, just sometimes. If I break on all exceptions then Xcode will break on the save call, but if I turn off breakpoints it will just hang forever, no crashes or anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any custom managed object validation? What is the stack trace if you press the debugger pause button?

Comment: Do you access MOC from more than 1 thread?

Comment: That was it! I created the context on one thread than accessed it from another thread. Now I create a new context on the other thread and it seems to be working. Thanks! Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @edc1591 I've just posted an answer, haven't seen your comment earlier since you didn't use [at sign]piobyz ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hanging on anything that uses `ManagedObjectContext` is a sign of a deadlock. Either use [NSLocking protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSLocking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) or create a new `MOC` for each thread and [synchronize them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398646/core-data-managed-object-context-thread-synchronisation).

Another useful doc from Apple -> [Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1)

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried setting NSError *error to nil?