# Importing And saving large data into coredata blocks every thing and application quits

Tags: ios, core-data

I am developing an application in which huge amount of data has to fetched from web server and then this data has to be stored in core data.

I am using private Contexts for that like:

```
[privateContext performBlockAndWait:^{ //Code }];
```

Firstly I was calling this block from background thread by using dispatch queues. But the core data was not functioning well. Then I read the documentation and found out that this block has to be called from the main thread. And after that everything worked fine.

But now the problem is that during data storing if I press the home button and come back again to application the UI of application hangs and after sometime the application crashes with no crash log. And I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Another thing if I call this block from background thread this problem does not happen, but then the other issues starts arriving.

Comment: Study examples shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9082584/78305

Comment: I have followed these instructions but my problem is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the complete code that is performing the block?

Are you receiving any memory warnings during the execution of the app?
Are you storing and fetching in small batches or are you fetching all your data and storing it at once?

My educated guess is the following:

performBlockAndWait is blocking the main thread. When you suspend the app and resume it again, the main thread will continue to be blocked (therefore the UI will not be updated as the main thread is in charge of UI updates). If you have large amounts of data in memory for storage AND your app is blocking the main thread, your app is being terminated due to memory usage or non responsiveness.

I don't understand why do you have problems doing this operation in a background thread, I've used it multiple times and everything worked like a charm. I've used NSOperationQueue with block and in the applicationWillResignActive I create a background task to ensure that the operation is finished up before suspending the app.

If you can provide more info.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not receiving any memory warnings. And I am going to post full code. I have edited my question.

Comment: I cannot post the full function as it is not allowing me to do because of character limit.